# Why parallel cyclic reduction to solve a tridiagonal system is not scaling well in openMP?

Tags: c, openmp, openmpi

Here is my openMP code to solve a tridiagonal system by applying parallel cyclic reduction. I have taken 3 systems of size 256000, 512000 and 1024000, and solve them using the number of threads 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 24, respectively, on a Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3 processor.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>

int num_sys = 1;

void data_construct(double *h_b, double *h_c, double *h_d, double *h_y, int size)
{
int i, j;
for(j = 0; j<num_sys; j++)
    for(i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        int id = j*size + i;
        h_b[id] = 2.0; h_c[id] = 8.0; h_d[id] = 2.0; h_y[id] = 8.0;
            
        if(i == 0)
           h_b[id] = 0.0; 
             
        if(i == size-1)
             h_d[id] = 0.0; 
    }
}


void PCR_Tri_openMP(double *b, double *c, double *d, double *y, double *x, int steps, int n)
{
 double *bb, *cc, *dd, *yy;     
 bb = (double*)malloc(n*num_sys*sizeof(double));     cc = (double*)malloc(n*num_sys*sizeof(double));       
 dd = (double*)malloc(n*num_sys*sizeof(double));     yy = (double*)malloc(n*num_sys*sizeof(double));

int i, k, iLeft, iRight;

double alfa, beta;      int delta = 1;

for(k = 0; k<steps; k++) // reduction loop
{
    if(k != 0) //from lavel 1 updated data is copying back to original memory location before starting the reduction
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(i = 0; i<n*num_sys; i++)    // each thread copying
        {
            b[i] = bb[i];   c[i] = cc[i];   d[i] = dd[i];   y[i] = yy[i];
        }
    }       
    
    #pragma omp parallel for private(iLeft, iRight, alfa, beta)
    for(i = 0; i<n*num_sys; i++) // each thread is performing k-th level reduction
    {       
        iLeft  = i - delta;     iRight = i + delta;
    
        if(i%n - delta < 0)     iLeft = (i/n)*(n);
        if(i%n + delta >= n)    iRight = (i/n + 1)*n - 1;

        alfa =  b[i]/c[iLeft];  beta = d[i]/c[iRight];

        cc[i] = c[i] - d[iLeft]*alfa - b[iRight]*beta;
        yy[i] = y[i] - y[iLeft]*alfa - y[iRight]*beta;
        bb[i] = -b[iLeft]*alfa;
        dd[i] = -d[iRight]*beta;
    }
    delta *= 2;         
}

#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i<n*num_sys; i++)
    x[i] = yy[i]/cc[i];
}


int main()
{     
 int syssize[3] = {256000, 512000, 1024000};    
 int NT[6] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24};
 
 int i, j, k, size;     double t1, t2;
            
 for(k = 0; k<3; k++)
 {
    size = syssize[k];
    
    double *h_b, *h_c, *h_d, *h_x, *h_y;
    h_b = (double*)malloc(num_sys*size*sizeof(double));
    h_c = (double*)malloc(num_sys*size*sizeof(double));
    h_d = (double*)malloc(num_sys*size*sizeof(double));
    h_x = (double*)malloc(num_sys*size*sizeof(double));
    h_y = (double*)malloc(num_sys*size*sizeof(double));
    
    int step = ceil(log(size)/log(2.0));
                
    for(i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {   
        double sum = 0.0;
        omp_set_num_threads(NT[i]);

        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp single nowait
            printf("number of threads = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }       
       
        for(j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            data_construct(h_b, h_c, h_d, h_y, size);
            t1 = omp_get_wtime();
                PCR_Tri_openMP(h_b, h_c, h_d, h_y, h_x, step, size);
            t2 = omp_get_wtime();
            sum += t2-t1;
        }   
                    
        printf("%d\t %d\t %lf\n", size, NT[i], sum/10.0);
                    
    }
     free(h_b);   free(h_c);   free(h_d); free(h_y);    free(h_x); 
}
 
return 0;
}
```

Here is the
[performance result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geR6p.png)

I do not why I lost performance for more threads, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can list at least two problems from looking at your code and at the results

1. Your input sizes are too small. Even for a single thread, the total work done is too small, and the execution time is less than 1 second. When the input is too small, the total work per thread will be even smaller as the number of thread grows. In such scenarios, time spent in overheads of OpenMP inner functions will be more significant in relation to the total execution time.
2. You are creating and destroying too many parallel regions. Each time you create and destroy a parallel region, you are wasting time with OpenMP overheads.

Try to create just a single parallel region for the `PCR_Tri_openMP` function, wrapping the outermost for loop. If you need explicit synchronization between threads, you can use the `barrier` directive. `for` directive also already have implicit barriers.